# how to select which USB to send cmds to out of 2 usbs?

Tags: python, select, usb

I have 2 of the same devices. They have different serial numbers-SN-01, and SN-02. How do I select which one to send commands to?

Comment: This is a very general, vague question. Without a [mre] of how you're sending the info, or any info about the libraries you're using, it'd be impossible for anyone to give anything more than a general, vague answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.